# Inno Setup WinHttpRequest with optional certificate

Tags: https, inno-setup, client-certificates, pascalscript, winhttprequest

I have a tomcat server configured to use TLS and client certificate authentication optionally.

Currently I am trying to establish a connection using Inno Setup with `WinHttpRequest`:

```pascal
WinHttpReq := CreateOleObject('WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1');
WinHttpReq.Open('POST', 'https://localhost:8443/api/validate', False);
WinHttpReq.Option(4) := '&H3300';
```

HTTPS errors are ignored; but receive this error message since I'm not setting any certificate for client validation:

> A certificate is required to complete client authentication

So, what should I do to tell `WinHttpReq` that I don't have any certificate and continue?

I have tried using `WinHttpSetOption`:

```pascal
WinHttpSetOption(WinHttpReq, WINHTTP_OPTION_CLIENT_CERT_CONTEXT, WINHTTP_NO_CLIENT_CERT_CONTEXT, 0);
```

But it is not an Inno Setup Pascal scripting valid function.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi. Did you ever find a fix for this?